# Using a colour wheel as a colour ramp for displaying directional data in Arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, symbology, color-ramp

I would like to define a colour ramp for displaying direction data in a 'smooth' fashion. So for data in degrees there wouldn't be a jump in colour between 359 and 0 degrees. It seems to me a colour wheel would be great for this.  I haven't seen this done, the preset ramps in arc don't do it, but I would think someone must have.

My question is how to implement this. My thought is to combine a ramp from red through yellow to green with one from green through blue to red (or whatever the proper quadrant colours are) and map that to 0 through 90 to 180 and 180 through 270 to 360. But I don't know how to set this up. Any ideas on how to define the ramps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no colour wheel, but you can match it quite with a customized color ramp. Go to the graduated colour, **right click on a color ramp**, then you can add to color ramps in order to have the starts and ends with the same colour. In the example below I used multiple alorithmic color ramps with CIE transitions.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have tried a few variations and am mostly satisfied. I found that dropping the saturation on every other ramp endpoint in hsv to 75 helped bring out the differences to my eye. Working with 6 secondary colors (6 ramps) seems to give intuitive results (red and green are opposite)